# What are default JVM options used by grails run-app

Tags: grails

According to this page:
http://grails.github.io/grails-howtos/en/performanceTuning.html#s3, the `grails run-app` command will provide some options to the JVM itself, such as `-XX:MaxPermSize`. So, my question is, what options are provided by the `grails run-app` command by default? The reason that I am asking this is that I am doing some benchmarking in the development mode, so I want to make sure that I am actually changing something when I provide JVM options through GRAILS_OPTS.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the detail in `startGrails.bat` present in

`GRAILS_HOME/bin/`

Default setting for `GRAILS_OPTS` (if not provided by user) looks like

```
GRAILS_OPTS=-server -Xmx768M -Xms64M 
-XX:PermSize=32m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

which gets overriden based on the command used. In case of `run-app` I think the default is used unless otherwise specified by user as environment variable.